# R shiny: Error in chart$html : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write interactive piecharts using Shiny but keep getting this error

```
Error in chart$html : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have 3 data sets, one has the whole data set, one is how many things were passed and the other is how many failed. I've the following code:

### **server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

y1<-read.csv("y1.csv")
y2<-read.csv("y2.csv")
y3<-read.csv("y3.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset,
             "full content" = y1,
             "passed content" = y2,
             "failed content" = y3, select = "full content")
    })



 output$view <- renderGvis({
      dok <-gvisPieChart(datasetInput(), options=list(width=500, height=500))
      plot(dok)
    })
  })
```

### ui.R

```
# ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Degree of knowledge distribution for content"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "Choose:", 
                choices = c("full content", "passed content", "failed content"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("view")
  )
))
```

My y csv files are 5 observations of two variables, the name of the content and the number of them

Comment: You do not need to use `plot(dok)` in `renderGvis`, just return `dok`.

Comment: Thank you, although this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: It should if you use `output$view <- renderGvis({
      gvisPieChart(datasetInput(), options=list(width=500, height=500))
    })`, if not make a reproducible example that we can have the same error as you.

Comment: If I remove the `plot(dok)` the graph isn't showing up at all.

Comment: To enter the data manually use
`a <- c("", "DOK: 1", "DOK: 2", "DOK: 3" , "DOK:4")
b<- c(1133, 188490, 1113503, 354549, 37575)
y1 <- rbind(t(a), t(b))
y1 <- t(y1)
y1 <- as.data.frame(y1)
a <- c("", "DOK: 1", "DOK: 2", "DOK: 3" , "DOK:4")
b<- c(471, 131622, 718006, 203689, 19200)
y2 <- rbind(t(a), t(b))
y2 <- t(y2)
y2 <- as.data.frame(y2)
a <- c("", "DOK: 1", "DOK: 2", "DOK: 3" , "DOK:4")
b<- c(662, 56868, 395497, 150560, 18375)
y3 <- rbind(t(a), t(b))
y3 <- t(y3)
y3 <- as.data.frame(y3)`

Comment: Open the app in your browser, you need an internet connection.

Comment: The window opens and the side bar is working, just the graph isn't appearing

Comment: It works for me (by using `as.numeric(as.character())` on the second column of yours data.frames because there are factors), try to run the example in `?renderGvis` : `shiny::runApp(system.file("shiny/", package="googleVis"))`, do you see the scatterplot ?

Comment: Thank you, it ran once and now I'm getting an error `Data has to be a data.frame. See ?data.frame for more details.`

Comment: It's running now, thank you!